# Where to close SQLiteOpenHelper when opened in my application's onCreate?

Tags: android, sqliteopenhelper

I read that it was better to use only one `SQLiteOpenHelper` instance in a class extending `Application`:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    private static SQLiteOpenHelper dBHelper;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        dBHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    }

    public static SQLiteDatabase getDB() {
        return dBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
}
```

but in that case, where should I close it?

Thanks

Jul

Comment: You can call it in `finally` block like :  `@Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        try
        {
        dBHelper = new DBHelper(this);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
         
        }
        finally{
         dBHelper.close();
        }
    }` . If you want to close the database helper after calling it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always have one and only one `SQLOpenHelper` instance and you should never close it. More detailed explanation can be found [here](http://touchlabblog.tumblr.com/post/24474750219/single-sqlite-connection) and [here](http://touchlabblog.tumblr.com/post/32793099735/training-sqlite)

Answer (score 0):

You may close the database in the `onTerminate()` method of the `Application` subclass. If your application can handle a closed database (by reopening ...) you can additionally close in the `onLowMemory()` method (but this will not free much memory).

More important is that you close any database cursors if you are finished using them.

EDIT

vmirnonov is right, `onTerminate()` is only called in the emulator, so ignore that part of the answer.

Comment: according to the documentation `onTerminate` is never called